# equivalent of RxJS.pausable(Observable) for RxJava

Tags: java, rx-java, reactive-programming, rxjs, rx-android

I search for a equivalent of [RxJS.pausable(Observable)](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/pausable.md) for RxJava.

Currently I have the following but it looks a little bit strange. Is there a better way?

```java
PublishSubject<Boolean> allValidSubject = PublishSubject.create();
PublishSubject<Void> clickSubject = PublishSubject.create();

allValidSubject
      .switchMap(valid -> valid ? clickSubject : Observable.empty())
      .skipUntil(allValidSubject)
// ...
```

At the end I have two observables. One for input validation and one for a send button click event.

Comment: Are you trying to validate some form input and proceed after the button is clicked if the input is correct? If you are, then `combineLatest` is usually the answer...

Comment: Well that's not cool, at least close the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think something like this would do it.

```
Observable<String> event = Observable.just("My Input");
// false - paused by default
final BehaviorSubject<Boolean> pauser = BehaviorSubject.create(false);

event
    .flatMap(new Func1<String, Observable<String>>() {
        @Override
        public Observable<String> call(final String input) {
            return pauser
                    .distinctUntilChanged()
                    .filter(new Func1<Boolean, Boolean>() {
                        @Override
                        public Boolean call(Boolean resumed) {
                            return resumed;
                        }
                    })
                    .map(new Func1<Boolean, String>() {
                        @Override
                        public String call(Boolean resumed) {
                            return input;
                        }
                    });
        }
    })
    .subscribe(new Action1<String>() {
        @Override
        public void call(String input) {
            // handle input
        }
    });
```

To resume/pase:

```
pauser.onNext(true);
pauser.onNext(false);
```

Event observable can be replaced with combineLatest how suggested above, but it is per use case, and still can be flatMapped. Same fasle/true could be pushed onto pauser, that's where distrinctUntilChanged kicks in to avoid resume or pause if already resumed/paused.